# On the computational efficiency of some matlab code when finding the loglikelyhood

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, matlab

I am looking at some code on GAS models [found here](http://gasmodel.com/code.htm) (number 7).

The code finds the log-likelihood of the joint conditional distribution of each observation by summing up the single log-likelihood of each observation in a for loop.

In pseudocode

```
for t = imaxpq+1:cT
     find the parameter of the conditional distribution of the t observation
     compute the log-likelyhood and save it as dllik
     dloglik = dloglik + dllik
end
```

After having done this and thus having found the log-likelihood of the joint density function the code proceeds to do the maximization (to obtain the maximum likelihood) but first does this:

```
dloglik = double(dloglik/cT);
```

It then inputs to the maximization function dloglik and after getting the return from the maximization it multiplies it by cT.

My questions are two: What is the use of the double function in this case? Why not simply input the log-likelihood in the maximization function and obtain the max value without needing to divide and the multiply by cT?

Doesn’t dividing by cT the input and the multiplying the output back by cT increase the error on the critical value?

Comment: My guess is that this is related to scaling for the optimizer. Don't know about Matlab, but you can check the scale of the unscaled likelihood, and optimize against that, and see if the optimizer handles it as well, and finds the same solution.